# Silverlight button Mouse Over like hover effect

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I created button with style but after creating button style it looses default effect of the button and when I directly put attribute in button than I will get those default effects like when I click I can see blue background.I also try to put Visual Manager but it is not working. Kindly somebody can help me to know what  I am doing wrong

My Button Style:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MenuButtonStyle">
  <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
  <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Sitka Heading"/>
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <Grid>
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
              <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonTextElement"
                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                  To="Blue"/>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" 
                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="normalImage">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" 
                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="mouseOverImage">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonTextElement"
                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                  To="Blue"/>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" 
                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="normalImage">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" 
                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="mouseOverImage">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0.5" Margin="30,0,0,0"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
          <TextBlock x:Name="ButtonTextElement" 
                     Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="30,0"
                     Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Grid.Column="0" 
                     VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" />
          <Image x:Name="normalImage" Source="/Assets/menu-arrow-left.png" 
                 Grid.Column="1" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                 Margin="0,0,30,0" />
          <Image x:Name="mouseOverImage" Source="/Assets/menu-arrow-left-hover.png"
                 Grid.Column="1" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                 Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="0,0,30,0" />
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

I also change in VisualStateManager like this

```
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverVisualElement" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="TextBlock.Foreground" To="Red" />
```

`My Button Tag`

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonStyle}" Content="Home"/>
```

Comment: Hope somebody will help me on this.Please

Comment: checked your xaml. The background of your root grid is null, therefore the mouseHover is not properly detected. You can set any backgroundcolor you want, you can even set it to Transparent. But you have to set it and the hover shall be detected properly.

Comment: @Martin in many cases the background thing would be an issue to get the hittestvisibility, but since it's a control template, that's inherited automatically by control. So that won't fix it either. I'll swing by this later if I have time and make an example.

Comment: I did all suggestion given by you guys. Pressed event is working very good  but MouseOver I could not get it work. I will post my updated code in the same Question

Comment: @Milind: I took your xaml and tried it. Yes you are right, the MouseOver state is not working. Then I looked at your code and saw why: you really deleted the MouseOver state completely, how on earth do you expect your control to show any reaction on MouseOver if you do not provide the VisualState?

Comment: @Martin Ok I now I added MoverOver Effect still it is not working, Kindly can you have a look on it.

Comment: @ChrisW. W. I am really sorry to disturb you guys as this is my first project and I am learning. If you guys help me than, I can do more coding.

Comment: Hi, Guys any solution for this..

Comment: @Milind: I just tried out your xaml and it is working fine. The MouseOver state shows as expected (I haven't checked the images). What exactly is not working when you try it?

Comment: @Martin when I run the app in windows mobile emulator and try to put mouse over the text and image it will not give animation effect which make in MouseOver state :(

Comment: @Martin Yes I did for sure.

Comment: @Milind: I can think of several things that might be the problem: 1. I don't know how big your images are and if they might overlap the text and are hittestvisible, they might swallow the moseover events, try removing them. 2. maybe you have seen an outdated version when testing, and the xaml I checked for you is actually NOT the same xaml that ran when you tried it with the emulator. 3. the emulator might have a glitch concerning the moseover.

Comment: @Martin For a while I am awarding points to you as help me lot and I am looking mouseover is not need in my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your template. First: You have to make sure that the element identified by `Storyboard.TargetName` and its property (you want to change) identified by `Storyboard.TargetProperty` actually make sense. You can change the color of a `SolidColorBrush`, and you can use a `SolidColorBrush` for a `Textblock.Foreground` property, but you cannot directly set the foreground property color, because foreground actually is a `Brush` (not a `Color`). Second: if you override the template of a control you have to provide all the `VisualStates` that are in the original template, that means you have to define the `FocusStates` as well.
Here is a template that does what you are trying to do:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <Grid>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                        <Storyboard>

                            <ColorAnimation
                                Duration="0"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonTextElement"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                To="Red"/>

                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation
                                Duration="0"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="Background"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                To="#FF6DBDD1"/>
                            <ColorAnimation
                                Duration="0"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonTextElement"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                To="Red"/>


                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Duration="0"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                To=".55"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Duration="0"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                To="1"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Border
                x:Name="Background"
                Background="White"/>
            <TextBlock
                x:Name="ButtonTextElement"
                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                FontSize="20" FontFamily="Sitka Heading" 
                Foreground="Black"/>

            <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" Margin="1" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

The [default button style can be found on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278069%28VS.95%29.aspx).

Comment: Hi Thank you for the reply with snippet of the code. But as usual I could get pressed state get working but mouse over is not working, what can be the reason

Comment: @Milind: Show your updated xaml, otherwise I can't answer _"mouse over is not working, what can be the reason"_. And follow the advise given by Chris W. about removing that `VisualTransition`. @Chris W.: I normaly would introduce a separate element as visualState indicator for each VisualState too. Just trying to get the OP's template working.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this page:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278069(VS.95).aspx

and see this page:
http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/Silverlight/SampleBrowser/index.htm#/?sref=CustomTemplateSamples&id=4

there are a sample for mouse over with templete

Answer (score 0):

Make sure VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups is the direct child of the root element of your ControlTemplate. In your example, your root element is a Border, so put the VisualStateManager stuff directly under the Border tag.